# Create table merging two tables Ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table A: Entry

```
id_1, Name_1, col_2 
id_2, Name_1, col_3 
id_3, Name_1, col_4
```

Table B: Entry

```
id, Name_1, Code_1, Code_2
```

Now I want to create a new Table C which joining based on entry Name_1

```
id_1, Name_1, col_2 ,Code_1, Code_2 
id_2, Name_1, col_3 , Code_1, Code_2
id_3, Name_1, col_4 , Code_1, Code_2
```

How can I write a script which performs the above task

Comment: using join to get your output  ex : select Id,Name,Col,Code1,Code2 where id=id_1

Comment: @SenthilKumar I din get you. I am thinking of looping on one table. Can you share some example or reference for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join as shown below

```
select sp.Name,cb.col from table1 as cb join table2 as sp on cb.nale= sp.name
```